# Origem de "custar os olhos da cara"

Tags: expressões, origem, girias

No Brasil (não sei se em Portugal também) a expressão "custar o(s) olho(s) da cara" é usada para dizer que algo custa muito dinheiro. Exemplo:

> —Por que você não comprou aquela TV?
>
> —Porque estava custando os olhos da cara. (o preço estava muito alto)

Eu escuto a expressão tanto no singular ("o olho") quanto no plural ("os olhos"), sempre com o mesmo significado.

Pesquisei sobre a origem e só encontrei aqueles [artigos pouco confiáveis](http://www.historiadetudo.com/custar-olhos-cara) (sem fonte, baseados em nada), dizendo que há várias possibilidades:

- um consquistador espanhol perdeu o olho em um conflito com os Incas e afirmou que defender a Coroa Espanhola lhe custou um olho da cara
- povos da Antiguidade tinham a tradição de arrancar os olhos dos prisioneiros de guerra
- [lenda obrigatória envolvendo a Grécia antiga](https://www.significados.com.br/custar-os-olhos-da-cara/)

Entre outros. Nenhum dos sites cita fontes, então qual é a origem desta expressão?

Comment: Também se diz em Portugal. Se o Diego Almagro disse isso, de certeza não foi perante o Imperador Carlos V (o artigo diz que foi): ele viajou para  o Novo Mundo em 1514 e por lá ficou até morrer. A etimologia popular é muito criativa :)

Comment: Essa expressão é de origem francesa, eu acho: couter les yeux de la tête. Dizem que começou no século XiX no sites franceses, com escritores como o Balzac.

Comment: A expressão faz sentido: a visão é um sentido essencial, muito caro a todos nós, e aquele que a perde fica dependente de outras pessoas para quase tudo.  Mas... não seria um pleonasmo?  Afinal, temos outros olhos que não os da cara?

Comment: @Centaurus Bem, existe o chamado "terceiro olho"...

Comment: Hugo, já que ele foi citado, acho que em muitas situações  a expressão "custou-me o terceiro olho" até poderia ser usada, em sentido figurado, é claro.

Comment: @Lambie, em francês também só encontrei a partir do século XIX. Mas em português e espanhol já se encontra no século XVI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A expressão existe em várias línguas, mas a sua origem parece ser ibérica. Encontro exemplos em português desde 1560 e em castelhano desde 1528 [(“hame costado los ojos de la cara”; CORDES¹)](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=hame%20costado%20los%20ojos%20de%20la%20cara&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000); em italiano apenas a partir de 1780 [(“costare gli occhi della testa”)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=nZVNAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1615&dq=%22un%20occhio%20della%20testa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4kqTG8OjTAhVDlxoKHbIKAX4Q6AEI_wIwMQ#v=onepage&q=%22un%20occhio%20della%20testa%22&f=false), e em francês a partir de 1842 [(“coûter les yeux de la tête”)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/co%C3%BBter_les_yeux_de_la_t%C3%AAte). Encontra-se cerca do ano de 1140 “perdieré los averes mas los ojos de la cara e aun demás los cuerpos e las almas” ([conforme o original no CORDES](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=que%20perderi%E9%20los%20averes%20e%20m%E1s%20los%20ojos%20de%20la%20cara&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) e [texto em espanhol moderno](http://recursostic.educacion.es/eda/web/tic_2_0/informes/garcia_monedero_gloria/EL_CID/quest5_2.html)) mas não é claro se o sentido é aqui literal ou figurado.

O primeiro exemplo que encontrei em português é de [Jorge Ferreira de Vasconcellos, *Comédia Eufrosina,* 1560](http://purl.pt/12154/6/#/316)  (Ato 5, cena 8, p. 309; facsimile do original e grafia atual por baixo):

[image]
(Porque também se o mandar matar, ele não tem que perder, e eu perco-me e custar-me-á a cavalgada os olhos da cara.)

*Custar os olhos da cara* é uma metáfora perfeitamente transparente. A indústria da etimologia popular gosta de explicações assentes em episódios ou práticas particulares. Poderão até ter existido vários episódios e práticas ao longo do tempo, mas um fator essencial e suficiente para a origem e popularidade da expressão é facto de os olhos serem algo muito precioso. Encontramos aliás no passado *olhos da cara* como metáfora para ‘valor elevado’ numa variedade contextos, não só na expressão *custar os olhos da cara*. Ainda na [*Comédia Eufrosina* de 1560](http://purl.pt/12154/6/#/260) (Ato 4, cena 8, p. 252) é-nos dito que não queiramos ser amigos das alcoviteiras, porque se lhe dermos a mão, elas vão querer o braço:

> elas tem por lei o provérbio, Quem dá e não dá sempre, quanto dá tanto perde. Que **lhe tenhais dado os olhos da cara**, tanto sentem a bolsa seca, morto é o afilhado, porque tínhamos o compradado.

Bento Pereira regista em 1697 o adágio *deve os olhos da cara* [(Corpus do Português)](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/x.asp). Em castelhano encontro ainda mais e mais variados exemplos, logo a partir de 1511:

> y por mantener mi honor y fama reservo la parte por ti más deseada, la qual **te será guardada como los ojos de la cara**
>   [(Anónimo, *Traducción de Tirante el Bçanco de Joanot Martorell,* 1511; CORDES.¹)](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=nin%20las%20osar%EDa%20tomar%20por%20los%20ojos%20de%20la%20cara&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000)
>
> iuían en tan gran asosiego & en tan gran paz que non tomaua vn ome armas contra otro **nin las osaría tomar por los ojos de la cara,** ca el rey era mucho ardid & muy atreuido en armas, & tan justiciero que tan abondada fue la justicia que […]
>   [(Anónimo, *Crónica Popular del Cid,* 1512; CORDES.¹)](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=110517%5C023%5CC003O11052017230835392.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20ojos%20de%20la%20cara%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D1200-1799%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1)

Finalmente há a questão de porquê *olhos da cara* e não simplesmente *olhos*. Encontro no passado *olhos na cara* numa variedade de contextos, não apenas para exprimir figuradamente ‘valor elevado’. Muitas vezes é por oposição a “olhos” do entendimento, alma, coração, etc., como em [Padre João Pereira, *Exhortaçoens Domesticas Feytas no Collegios, e Cazas da Companhia de Jesus, de Portugal, & Brasil*, Coimbra, 1715:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Xs4D1kekI3oC&pg=PA542&dq=%22olhos%20da%20cara%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq8evE_ejTAhUJvRoKHYTkDnI4MhDoAQglMAA#v=onepage&q=%22olhos%20da%20cara%22&f=false)

> Santa Luzia tirando os olhos, naõ ficou sem elles ; porque naõ via cõ os olhos da cara; via com os olhos do entendimento

Mas noutros exemplos não é por oposição a nada, como neste exemplo em castelhano, no [*Poema de Mio Cid* de cerca de 1140:](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=bes%F3le%20la%20boca%20e%20los%20ojos%20de%20la%20cara&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000)

> [...] besóle la boca e los ojos de la cara.

Ou este outro de [Camilo de Castelo Branco, *Cenas da Foz,*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=61YUDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT36&dq=%22olhos%20da%20cara%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU8Nn0qerTAhVJrRoKHWVYAY0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22olhos%20da%20cara%22&f=false) originalmente publicado em 1857:

> D. Vicência era vistosa e farfalhuda. Meneavase trejeitando com tamanha volúpia, que eram pouco **os dois olhos da cara** para a verem!

Parece que *olhos da cara* é de há muito uma frase feita. Pode ser que *da cara* seja acrescentado simplesmente por uma questão de prosódia e ênfase; para ajudar o ouvinte a formar uma imagem mais viva na sua imaginação. Parece ser comum neste tipo de expressões acrescentar elementos superficialmente redundantes, mas que poderão ter este efeito de avivar a imagem: a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/dente) regista, com o mesmo significado de *custar os olhos da cara, custar os dentes da boca* (não temos outros; atestado já em 1759 nas [*Infermidades da lingua*](https://archive.org/details/infermidadesdal01paivgoog/page/n133)); também dizemos *ver com estes olhos que a terra há de comer* e *pagar com o suor do seu rosto* (*seu suor* seria suficiente).

---

¹ [REAL ACADEMIA ESPAÑOLA](http://www.rae.es/): Banco de datos (CORDE) [em linha]. [*Corpus diacrónico del español*](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/corde). Consultas em 12-5-2017. Para ver o texto, na página do CORDES, ao fundo, clicar em “recuperar”, e na página seguinte clicar no texto em azul para ver o texto envolvente.

Comment: Bem interessante.  Parece que em português antigo o pronome oblíquo em ênclise era escrito da mesma forma que no espanhol moderno: "eu percome"

Comment: @Centaurus, é verdade. Nunca vi tracinhos em textos desses tempos. Mas creio que já vi coisas como *custar hia*